# Global proof of Serre duality

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Does anyone know of a global proof (involving no local argument) of Serre duality at the level of varieties or manifolds (as opposed to schemes).

Comment: Could you clarify what "no local argument" means?  Is the Hodge theorem a "local argument" because being harmonic is a local condition?  

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might like the proof in section 5.3 of Voisin's book *Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry*.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd offer a high-tech alternative for certain varieties. If $X$ is smooth and projective over a field $k$ then Bondal and van den Bergh give a proof in *[Generators and representability of functors in commutative and noncommutative geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204218)* that $D^b(\mathrm{Coh}X)$ is saturated which is a strong representability condition on cohomological/homological functors to the category of $k$ vector spaces. It follows immediately that $D^b(\mathrm{Coh}X)$ has a Serre functor by using the fact that $Hom(A,-)^*$ is representable for every bounded complex of coherent sheaves $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Since a $\bar{\partial}$-Operator is an elliptic Operator, you can use elliptic theory in order to prove the Serre duality. In fact the Serre duality is a kind of corollary of the"fundamental theorem" (as I Know it). In fact, you do not need the Hodge theorem, since the Hodge theorem itself is a corollary of the theorem.

For a reference of this "fundamental theorem" (perhaps slightly reformulated) I would refer to one of the following:

- Wells, Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds;
- Gilkey, Invariance Theory, the Heat Equation and the Atiyah Singer Index Theorem

(a complete proof for pseudodifferential operators)

- Warner, Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds

(the theorem is included as an exercise on the last page

- Kazdan, Lecture Notes on Applications of Partial Differential Equations to Some Problems in Differential Geometry (online available  [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/japan/japan.pdf))

(Corollary 2.5, for a sketch of the proof)

Answer (score 3):

I like the presentation from Analytic methods in algebraic geometry by Demailly. Here is the link: http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/eem2007.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the one in Griffiths and Harris?  That's at least rather different from the general nonsense one in Hartshorne.